# How to make a Jquery Ajax request hit a Rails Controllers json format?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Jquery ajax request which I'm using to UPDATE a record.  I'm trying to get back the JSON object to use in the success/error callback but the object `msg` is always the full rendered html.  How can I have this request hit the `format.json` in the users#update method?

**edit.html.erb**

```
<script>
    // when the #email_field_(id) field changes
    var email_timeout;
    $("#email_field_<%= @user.id %>").keypress(function() {
        clearTimeout(email_timeout);
        email_timeout = setTimeout(function(){ 
            $("#email_field_<%= @user.id %>").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                callback: "JSON",
                url: '<%= user_path(@user.id) %>',
                data: { _method:'PUT', user: { email : $("#email_field_<%= @user.id %>").val() } },
                success: function(msg) {
                    console.log(msg); //Always full rendered html
                    $("#email_field_<%= @user.id %>").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("#email_field_<%= @user.id %>").val(msg.email);
                },
                error: function(msg) {
                    $("#email_field_<%= @user.id %>").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("#email_field_<%= @user.id %>").val("<%= @user.email %>");
                    alert( "Ajax error!" );
                }
            });
        },1000);
    });
</script>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
# PATCH/PUT /users/1
# PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update(user_params)
      puts '****: ' + format.inspect
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render :json => { :error => "Error: unable to save data" }.to_json, :status => 422 }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you want you update controller to respond to both html and json requests ... ? if no then you should remove format.html lines in update function of rails controller

Comment: Is that the best solution, to have a dedicated update function for just json?

Comment: no that won't be a best solution but it will work ... for the best solution we should mention json request type in our ajax request ..... lets first try dataType: "json" in your ajax request .... and see if it works or not

Comment: if dataType: "json"  isn't working then your url should be something like this /users/1.json this will surely work and is the best solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You URL in ajax should be

```
url: '<%= "/user/#{@user.id}.json" %>'
```

also you should pass this in ajax request

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Comment: This worked.  I tested changing the url alone (`url: '<%= user_path(@user.id, :format => :json) %>'`), the dataType alone (`dataType: "json"`), and both together and in every case I got the json object back.  Huge thanks.